# Closed form solution?

Tags: calculus

Can a closed form solution be found for:

$$\intop_{0}^{K}e^{-\frac{\rho^{2}}{2c}}{}I_{0}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)\rho^{2}}{2c^{2}}}\right)d\rho,$$

where $a,b,c,K\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind?

Comment: maybe you can use : 

$$ I_0(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\frac{z^2}{4} \right)^k}{(k!)^2} $$

Comment: Because of upper limit $K$, you are asking for the indefinite integral.  First, can you do the special case $\int \exp(-x^2)I_0(x)\,dx$?

Comment: @GEdgar Unfortunately I can't find a solution for this either.

Comment: I solved a problem similar to this; I would see if there is anyway you could massage the equation to get it in the form of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution

Comment: For $K = \infty$, the integral is $$\begin{align}
& \int_0^{\infty} e^{-a^2x^2} I_0(x) dx\\
&\hspace0.5in 
= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-a^2 x^2} \left( \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} e^{x\cos\theta} d\theta\right) dx
= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a^2 x^2 + x\cos\theta} dx\right) d\theta
\\&\hspace0.5in 
= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi} a}\int_0^{\pi} e^{\frac{\cos\theta^2}{4a^2}} d\theta
= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi} a} e^{\frac{1}{8a^2}} \int_0^{\pi} e^{\frac{\cos2\theta}{8a^2}} d\theta
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 a} e^{\frac{1}{8a^2}} I_0(\frac{1}{8a^2})
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: let us use the power series expansion of the modified Bessel function as suggested by what'sup. A bit of notation to start:

$$ \frac{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)\rho^2}}{2c^2}:=\alpha\rho,$$

with $\rho\in[0,K]$ and $K>0$.

We need to compute the integrals

$$(k!)^2\mathcal I_k:=(-1)^k\frac{\alpha^{2k}}{4^k}\int_0^K \rho^{2k}e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}d\rho $$

for all $k\geq 0$. For $k=0$ we have

$$\mathcal I_0:=\int_0^K e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}d\rho=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}|c|}
\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{K}{\sqrt{2}|c|}\right).$$

and for $k=1$

$$\mathcal I_1:=-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\int_0^K \rho^2e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}d\rho=
-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\int_0^K (-c^2\rho)\left(-\frac{1}{c^2}\rho\rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}\right)d\rho= \\-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\left(-c^2\rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}|^K_0+c^2
\int_0^K e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}d\rho\right)=-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\left(-c^2Ke^{-\frac{K^2}{2c^2}}+c^2\mathcal I_0\right).
$$

For $k=2$ we have

$$2!\mathcal I_2:=\frac{\alpha^4}{4^2}\int_0^K \rho^4e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}d\rho=
\frac{\alpha^4}{4^2}\int_0^K (-c^2\rho^3)\left(-\frac{1}{c^2}\rho\rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}\right)d\rho= \\
\frac{\alpha^4}{4^2}\left(-c^2\rho^3 e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}|^K_0+3c^2
\int_0^K \rho^2e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2c^2}}d\rho\right)
=\frac{\alpha^4}{4^2}\left(-c^2K^3e^{-\frac{K^2}{2c^2}}\right)-3c^2\frac{\alpha^2}{4}\mathcal I_1.
$$

Can you go on and find a recursive formula for the $(k!)^2\mathcal I_k$?

EDIT

The recursive formula for $(k!)^2\mathcal I_k$ is

$$(k!)^2\mathcal I_k=\sum_{n=1}^k(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\frac{1}{4^k}K^{2n-1}e^{-\frac{K^2}{2}} +(-1)^k(2k-1)!!\frac{\mathcal I_0}{4^k},$$

in the easier case $\alpha=c=1.$

Comment: do you have the complete answer =) ? . (+1)

Comment: you really want to make me sweat with paper and pen :) (thanks for +1!)

Comment: $k$ is the exponent in the power series expansion $I_0(z)=1-z^2/4+...$ of the Bessel function. The idea is to evaluate the given integral for each exponent $k$ in such power series expansion.

Comment: @Avitus - I don't think this method will produce a closed form expression, do you disagree ?

Comment: @DaveS putting $\alpha=c=1$ I got $q!\mathcal I_q=-(-1)^q \frac{K^{2q-1}}{4^q}\exp(-\frac{K^2}{2})-\frac{(2q-1)}{4}(q-1)!\mathcal I_{q-1}$...this is a first step to the recursive formula. I admit that the method is quite long, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at only the case $K=\infty$:

By first checking the special case in GEdgar's comment, by comparing to the formula of the (-1)st moment of the Rice distribution (totally not allowed, I know...) we see that

$\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2)I_0(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}e^{1/8}\sqrt{\pi}I_0(\frac{1}{8})$,

which is verified with Wolfram Alpha.

In the general case, through some algebraic manipulations, using the same comparison we can posit that the answer to your integral, for $K = \infty$, MIGHT be (denoting $\gamma = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$):

$ \dots = \sqrt{\dfrac{c}{2}}\exp\left(\dfrac{\gamma^2}{4c}\right)\sqrt{\pi}L_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\dfrac{\gamma^2}{4c}\right)$,

where $L$ is a Laguerre polynomial.

Again, this has no reason to be correct (but it might be...)